# Typescript typing of an async lambda invocation from Api gateway

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an Api gateway on AWS that asynchronously calls a lambda function. What is the typescript typing for the lambda event? For a synchronous invocation I can use `APIGatewayProxyEvent` from `aws-lambda`, but I haven't found a typing for the async version.

There are differences, e. g. the synchronous version has a `event.requestContext.identity` property, while in the async invocation has no requestContent and identity is on the root level `event.identity`

```
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent } from "aws-lambda";
export const parseUserIdFromRequest = (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent | LOOKING_FOR_THIS_TYPE): string => {}
```